# Bond energy and tempetature

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

Does bond energy depend on temperature? Also why is it defined at 298 Kelvin if some substances cant be in gas phase in that temperature?

Comment: Specifying H and S at 298K is a standard in the thermodynamic community. Solids and liquids have vapor pressures above them, so substances can indeed be in the gas phase at 298K.

Comment: Bond energy does depend on temperature.